# Approximation of $L^{\infty}$-smooth functions.

Tags: functional-analysis

Can every $L^{\infty}$-smooth function on $\mathbb R$ be approximated by compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: What do you mean by $L^\infty$-smooth? Bounded and all derivatives bounded? If so, you cannot approximate constant functions with respect to the topology of uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$ of all derivatives.

Comment: @Jochen $L^{\infty}$-smooth means $L^{\infty}$ and infinitely differentiable. I didn't quite get your argument.

Comment: What is the topology?

Comment: @Jochen Topology of uniform convergence.

Comment: Well, then you cannot approximate the constant function $1$ because for every function $f$ with compact support you have $\sup\lbrace |1-f(x)|: x\in\mathbb R\rbrace \ge 1$.

Comment: @Jochen Okay, is there any topology in which this can be done?

Comment: Uniform convergence (of all derivatives if you like) on *all compact sets* -- but this is not a good topology on your space because it does not see boundedness (so that the space will not be complete).

Comment: @Jochen Thank you. It's clear to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative answer given by [Jochen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725858/approximation-of-l-infty-smooth-functions#comment1516139_725858):

> You cannot approximate the constant function $1$ by compactly supported functions uniformly on $\mathbb R$. Indeed, for every function $f$ with compact support,  $\sup\lbrace |1-f(x)|: x\in\mathbb R\rbrace \ge 1$.

A standard way to approximate smooth $F$ by smooth compactly supported functions is to take $F\varphi_n$, where $\varphi_n(x)=1$ for $|x|\le n$,  $\varphi_n(x)=1$ for $|x|\ge n+1$, and $\varphi_n$ is smooth. The convergence $F\chi_n\to F$ is uniform on every compact subset, but not on all of $\mathbb R$.